# IF STATEMENTS LOGIC

Tags: if-statement, sas, sas-macro

This is my thought logic for my if statements in SAS. It is not running because I was told I am using it improperly. Can someone provide assistance please?

> ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

```
data tmp_final_tab;
    merge data.final_alerts_ramts(in=a) data.final_alerts_repamts(in=b) data.final_alerts_passthru(in=c)
            data.final_alerts_wires(in=d) data.final_alerts_low_volume(in=e) data.final_alerts_bhvr(in=f);
    by clnt_no;
    if a;
        if pamt_activity_cr >= &rnd_pct_atl then atl_inda1 = 1; else atl_inda1 = 0;
        if pamt_activity_dr >= &rnd_pct_atl then atl_inda2 = 1; else atl_inda2 = 0;
    if b;
        if pamt_activity_cr >= &rnd_pct_atl then atl_indb1 = 1; else atl_indb1 = 0;
        if pamt_activity_dr >= &rnd_pct_atl then atl_indb2 = 1; else atl_indb2 = 0;
    if c;
        if (ptam/total_Amount) * 100 >= &pt_pct_atl then atl_indc = 1; else atl_indc = 0;
    if d;
        if tot_amt_wire >= &hrc_wire_amt_atl then atl_indd = 1; else atl_indd1 = 0;
        if tot_in_amt >= &wire_in_cnt_amt_atl then atl_indd2 = 1; else atl_indd2 = 0;
        if tot_out_amt >= &wire_out_cnt_amt_atl then atl_indd3 = 1; else atl indd3 = 0; 
    if e;
        if tot_amt_lv >= &lv_amt_atl then atl_ind = 1; else atl_ind = 0;
    if f;
        if tot_amt_bhvr >= &bhvr_w_hist_atl then atl_ind = 1; else atl_ind = 0;
    if a or b or c or d or e or f
        if (atl_inda + atl_indb + atl_indc + atl_indd + atl_inde + atl_indf > 0) then btl_ind = 0; else btl_ind = 1;
run;
```

Comment: Most of the IF statements indented at the same level as the BY statement are SUBSETTING IF statements, not IF/THEN statements.  The last one is missing the ending semi-colon.  Because of the subsetting IF statements your results will only include values of CLNT_NO that appear in all 6 of the input datasets.  Is it your intent to eliminate CLNT_NO values that are missing from one or more of the input datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `if` statement in SAS always has the following form (without `<>`):

```
if <boolean logic> then <code>;
```

If the evaluated logic needs to do more than one thing, it follows this form:

```
if <boolean logic> then do;
     <code>;
     <code>;
     <code>;
     ...
end;
```

It looks like all of your code creates binary variables. This programming shortcut in SAS will make binary 1/0 variables for you:

```
binary_var = (<boolean logic>);
```

If the logic is true, `binary_var` is 1. Otherwise, it is 0.

The correct form of your code is below with a cleaner form of your new binary variables.

```
data tmp_final_tab;
    merge data.final_alerts_ramts     (in=a) 
          data.final_alerts_repamts   (in=b) 
          data.final_alerts_passthru  (in=c)
          data.final_alerts_wires     (in=d) 
          data.final_alerts_low_volume(in=e) 
          data.final_alerts_bhvr      (in=f)
    ;

    by clnt_no;

    if a then do;
        atl_inda1 = (pamt_activity_cr >= &rnd_pct_atl);
        atl_inda2 = (pamt_activity_dr >= &rnd_pct_atl);
    end;

    if b then do;
        atl_indb1 = (pamt_activity_cr >= &rnd_pct_atl);
        atl_indb2 = (pamt_activity_dr >= &rnd_pct_atl);
    end;

    if c then atl_indc = ( (ptam/total_Amount) * 100 >= &pt_pct_atl);

    if d then do;
        atl_indd  = (tot_amt_wire >= &hrc_wire_amt_atl);
        atl_indd2 = (tot_in_amt >= &wire_in_cnt_amt_atl);
        atl_indd3 = (tot_out_amt >= &wire_out_cnt_amt_atl);
    end;

    atl_ind = ( (e AND tot_amt_lv >= &lv_amt_atl) OR (f AND tot_amt_bhvr >= &bhvr_w_hist_atl) );

    btl_ind = (sum(atl_inda, atl_indb, atl_indc, atl_indd, atl_inde, atl_indf) > 0);
run;
```

You technically do not even need `if` statements here. You can incorporate the dataset `in` logic into each binary variable (e.g. `binary_var = (a AND <logic>);`. If missing values are not needed from this operation, you can remove those `if` statements entirely.

Answer (score 0):

`if a;` is a [subsetting if](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/p1cxl8ifdt8u0gn12wqbji8o5fq1.htm) statement, and is very commonly used in merges like the above - although probably not what you *meant*.  Subsetting if means that the data step should stop executing and go to the next line if the `if` condition is not true.

In the case of the above, `if a;` is `true` if the current merged row includes some data from the first dataset (which has `in=a` in its dataset options).

It doesn't make sense to sprinkle them around like you did though - that suggests you really mean `if it comes from a then do these things`, not `if it doesn't come from a then drop it`.

Also, with all six (`if a; if b; if c;...`) then only rows that have some value in all six input datasets would be kept - an `inner join` - and then your last section doesn't make sense (the one with `or`).  But it would make more sense to do this:

`if a and b and c and d and e and f;`

---

One other note: there is the [`select`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/p09213s9jc2t99n1vx0omk2rh9ps.htm) statement, which sometimes can be useful in this sort of organization.  However, it would only be useful if you expected *only one* of the conditions to be true, or else wanted *only one* of them to be executed regardless of how many were true - it executes the first one that is true and then leaves.